# Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, text, properties

I am new at react.js and i am facing the error:

> Cannot read property 'text' of undefined.

My code is

```
    <body>
        <div id="react-container"> </div>
        <script type="text/babel">
       // React.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello World'), document.body);
       var MyComponent= React.createClass({
           render: function()
           {
              return <div>
              <h1>{this.probs.text}</h1>
              <p> </p>
              </div>;
           }
       });

       React.render(<div>
                    <MyComponent text="Hello World"/>
                    <MyComponent text="How Are You?"/> 
                    <MyComponent text="GoodBye!"/> 
                    </div>
                    , document.getElementById('react-container'));
</script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I am very confused that why i am getting this error.Please help me ou.

Answer (score 1):

`probs` should be `props` inside the `h1`